# Flextable row height after merging rows

Tags: r, ms-word, knitr, flextable

I have some data that requires some interesting formatting of cells. As such, I've placed the data into a FlexTable for this formatting. The issue is that after I do this cell merging, the top row and bottom row do not have uniform heights.

Here is some code with the cell merging commented out and the output. Below that, I've shown the output if the merging is uncommented. In the second image, you'll notice that rows 1 and 2 under columns IMP, NMP, SMP, and VFMP are different heights.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
createADFlexTable <- function(qCode = "clearCommunication") {
  bindADRows(qCode = qCode) %>% 
    flextable(col_keys = c("QuestionText", "Status_IMP", "Site_Perc_Agree_IMP", "Status_NMP", 
                           "Site_Perc_Agree_NMP", "Status_SMP", "Site_Perc_Agree_SMP", "Status_VFMP", 
                           "Site_Perc_Agree_VFMP", "ElectiveFlagText")) %>% 
    set_header_labels(QuestionText = "",
                      Status_IMP = "IMP",
                      Site_Perc_Agree_IMP = "IMP",
                      Status_NMP = "NMP",
                      Site_Perc_Agree_NMP = "NMP",
                      Status_SMP = "SMP",
                      Site_Perc_Agree_SMP = "SMP",
                      Status_VFMP = "VFMP",
                      Site_Perc_Agree_VFMP = "VFMP",
                      ElectiveFlagText = "Elective Flag \n(% Agreement)") %>% 
    border_remove() %>% 
    color(color = "#777777", part = "all") %>% 
    
    font(fontname = "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond", part = "all") %>% 
    fontsize(i = 2, size = 8, part = "body") %>% 
    fontsize(i = 2, j = c(1, ncol_keys(.)), size = 9, part = "body") %>% 
    fontsize(i = 1, size = 9, part = "body") %>%
    fontsize(i = 1, j = c("Status_IMP", "Status_NMP", "Status_SMP", "Status_VFMP"),
             size = 10) %>% 
    fontsize(size = 9, part = "header") %>%
       # merge_v(j = "QuestionText", part = "body") %>%
    # merge_v(j = "ElectiveFlagText", part = "body") %>%
    # merge_at(part = "header", j = c(2:3)) %>%
    # merge_at(part = "header", j = c(4:5)) %>%
    # merge_at(part = "header", j = c(6:7)) %>%
    # merge_at(part = "header", j = c(8:9)) %>%
    # merge_at(i = 2, j = c("Status_IMP", "Site_Perc_Agree_IMP")) %>%
    # merge_at(i = 2, j = c("Status_NMP", "Site_Perc_Agree_NMP")) %>%
    # merge_at(i = 2, j = c("Status_SMP", "Site_Perc_Agree_SMP")) %>%
    # merge_at(i = 2, j = c("Status_VFMP", "Site_Perc_Agree_VFMP")) %>%
    width(j = c("Status_IMP", "Status_NMP", "Status_SMP", "Status_VFMP"),
          width = 0.20) %>% 
    width(j = "QuestionText", width = 1.75) %>% 
    width(j = "ElectiveFlagText", width = 1.37) %>% 
    width(j = c("Site_Perc_Agree_IMP",
                "Site_Perc_Agree_NMP", "Site_Perc_Agree_SMP", "Site_Perc_Agree_VFMP"), width = 0.36)
}

createADFlexTable()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What the `bindADRows` function do? You don't have a reproducible example.